# Tried to get read file data to work, am missing the rest of the code

Tags: c#, structure, readfile

I am having trouble getting this to load, specifically with the indexing line. I was wondering if anyone knew how I would fill out the struct of these lines? The lines were sent from a friend whos code works but he didn't send me the rest and is busy. Ty in advance.

```
public static void readEmployees()
{
    int index = 0;
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\Test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);//Create file stream object with open and read modes
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);//Create file reader object
    streamReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);//Return carret to the start of the file
    for (string line = streamReader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = streamReader.ReadLine())//Read line and store in the string. Read till the read line is not empty.
    {
        string[] employee = line.Split(' ');//Split the read values by a space and returns each value to the array
        int employeeId = int.Parse(employee[0]);
        string employeeFirstName = employee[1];
        string employeeLastName = employee[2];
        double employeeIncome = double.Parse(employee[3]);
        double employeeKiwiSaverPercentage = double.Parse(employee[4]);
        employee Employee = new employee(employeeId, employeeFirstName, employeeLastName, employeeIncome, employeeKiwiSaverPercentage);
        static.employees[index] = Employee;//Store the values in the employee
        index++;
    }
    streamReader.Close();//Close the reader
    fileStream.Close();//Close the 
}
```

Comment: Which part is giving you the error? What do you mean by *indexing line*?

Comment: Where is `employees` declared?  Did you declare it outside of `Main`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need the rest plain and simple... code doesn't work unless you have all of it...you are asking for help fixing it, but we don't know the rest this code works but is worthless without the other pieces it's like doing a puzzle without the puzzle...